# Poor Bitmap clarity

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, pixel

I have some current bitmap instance on which I am drawing some shapes via `System.Drawing.Graphics`.
Is it possible somehow to draw shapes in better quality?

The current image quality looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, some pixels doesn't look really nice on arc borders.

```
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmap);
//Drawing first red arc

float redRotationAngle = CalculateRotationAngle(scaleDTO.startValue,
  scaleDTO.endValue,
  scaleDTO.redFinishTag);
gr.DrawArc(redPen, x, y, width, height, StartScaleAngle, redRotationAngle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable antialiasing for your drawing.

```
gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```